# - please explain me how can I change my ajax code to fetch api code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api, visual-web-developer

Here down below is my code written in ajax which basically lets me fetch data from a fact api for my personnel project

Ajax code to change into fetch API code

```
`var limit = 3;

 $.ajax({

 method: 'GET',

 url: 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/facts?limit=' + limit,

 headers: { 'X-Api-Key': 'YOUR_API_KEY'},

 contentType: 'application/json',

 success: function(result) {

 console.log(result);

},

error: function ajaxError(jqXHR) {

    console.error('Error: ', jqXHR.responseText);

}

});`
```

I have not really got any answer but I have tried to use this method below - please explain me in detail the whole concept.

Method 1 I tried was -
`async function fetchData(target, options){` // creating a fetch request and awaiting it till the response comes

```
    const fetch_data = await fetch(target, options);

  // storing the value of the response into a variable named results;

  const results = await fetch_data.json();

// running some tests to check the values  

console.log(results); 

}

// calling the function`

fetchData("https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/facts?limit=1",

{     method: "GET",`

Headers:{     "Content-Type": "application/json", 

'X-Api-Key': 'My api key'
}})
```